# Why image is not loading from url of android application?

Tags: android, image, web-services

I have created an android application where image is loading from given url.When I am passing url directly, the image is loading. But image is not loading when I am taking the url inside a string variable and passing that variable . My code is given below .

```
private Drawable ImageOperations(String url, String saveFilename) {
        try {
            String realImageUrl=url+"?  email="+Constants.email+"&proc_date="+Constants.proc_date+"&access_key="
            +Constants.ACCESS_KEY+"&version=1.00";

            String newUrl=realImageUrl.replace("https", "http");

            InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(newUrl);



            Log.e("https,SubString http: ",realImageUrl+","+ a);
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");

            return d;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,
            IOException {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        Object content = url.getContent();
        return content;
    }
```

This code is not working. my new url is newUrl. when I am printing newUrl in my log and giving that url directly instead of newUrl the image is loading.

Comment: 1. Please state clearly, what is **the exact** difference between code that works and code that doesn't (show code excerpts for both). 2. What does logcat say when you trigger fetching the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution. I have updated the fetch(String address) method.

```
public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,
            IOException {
        try{
        URL url = new URL(address);
        URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
        url = uri.toURL();
        Log.i("Url:", url+"");
        Object content = url.getContent();
        return content;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```